# LDAP search attributes

Tags: python, ldap

I have a search on my LDAP base which is:

```
user_account = server.search_s(
    'ou=usuarios,ou=xxx,o=system xxx',
    ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL,
    'uid=' + login,
    ['uid', 'mail', 'objectClass', 'CPF'])[0]
  if user_account[1]['CPF'] is not None:
    plpy.debug("It has CPF")
```

That's working fine if the CPF field is filled, but if it's not filled it gives me an error:

```
ERROR:  KeyError: 'CPF'
```

I have tried to do:

```
if user_account[1]['CPF'] is None:
    plpy.debug("It hasn't CPF")
```

But it's giving me the same error.

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: On that line: if user_account[1]['CPF'] is None:, but if the field is filled.. doesn't give me an error

Comment: You're checking if the value associated with key 'CPF' is None, however, your error is telling you there is no key 'CPF'. Check to see if it exists first.

Comment: i tried just if user_account[1]['CPF']:, but it didn't work as well...

Comment: I think i got it as if 'CPF' in user_account[1]:... thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get()` to get a value from a dictionary and return a default value if it's not there. If you supply no default value, it will return `None`.

```
cpf = user_account[1].get("CPF")
if cpf:
  plpy.debug("It has CPF")
```

Another way of doing this is using the `in` operator. It can tell you if a certain key exists in a dictionary.

```
if "CPF" in user_account[1]:
  plpy.debug("It has CPF")
```

This is the same as doing:

```
if "CPF" in user_account[1].keys():
  plpy.debug("It has CPF")
```